# Idiomatic way to share lens field definitions among modules

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

If I have two modules that both use `Control.Lens.TH`' `makeFields` to generate fields from a record, and a record in each of the different modules has the same field name, what's the best way of ensuring that the two modules are using the same definition of the `name` lens and the `HasName` class without having one of the modules depend on the other?

At the moment, I'm using another module named `SharedFields` with a single record with every field that needs shared, and then importing the `SharedFields` module in anything else that needs TH fields generated – but this is awkward and error-prone.

```
module First where

import Control.Lens

data First = First { firstName :: Bool }
  deriving (Read, Show, Eq)
makeFields ''First
```

---

```
module Second where

import Control.Lens

data Second = Second { secondName :: () }
  deriving (Read, Show, Eq)
makeFields ''Second
```

---

```
module Third (name) where

import First
import Second
```

Comment: Have you tried manually defining the `HasName` class in another module imported by both `First` and `Second`? That would seem idiomatic to me, and I think the Lens TH would use the existing class.

Comment: It works, but it's awkward having to manually define the classes for each field. Another TH function for splicing in each name would be better, but ideally I wouldn't have to list out *every* shared field name that's in my library

Comment: The problem is that the shared classes need to be defined in a module imported by both `First` and `Second`--you can't have "the same definition" defined in two modules. And of course that module can't know what fields are in either `First` or `Second` without getting into an impossible circularity problem.

Comment: Incidentally, I notice that I've just been echoing your second paragraph back to you. Sorry.

Comment: I encountered this same problem and resorted to a writing a bunch of gross Template Haskell. I ended up with a function that checks for the lens class and defines it if it doesn't exist yet. https://github.com/tfausak/strive/blob/v1.0.1/library/Strive/Internal/TH.hs#L46

Comment: I actually made a simple library that does exactly this: https://github.com/intolerable/shared-fields